# Content overflows when someone types a long word (with no spaces)

Tags: html, css

As you can in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/eoo7tb1e/) example the contents overflows when no space used. I tried `overflow: hidden` but that hides the rest of the word. Any ideas?

Comment: Give `word-wrap: break-word;` to the element.

Comment: This is normal behavior, you can break word with css or overflow ellipses, google for either

Comment: that breaks every "character" in a word.

Comment: @emreaydin149 It depends on the applied `width`. `10px` leaves no room.

Comment: And also please clarify what are you going to achieve? `Any ideas` to what?

Comment: Thanks Hashem, I didn't notice that 10px was to small for characters. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should increase the width of the `content` div and add the following style to the stylesheet:

```
.content {
     word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use of
`overflow:scroll;` or  `overflow:auto;` .

Setting overflow to scroll or auto will display scrollbars to reveal the additional text, while hidden will not.

Another idea is `text-overflow: ellipsis;`

as this [documentation](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/text-overflow/) says.

Hope these helps!